# How to save video to photo library iOS ionic

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, file-transfer

How to save video to photo library iOS ionic

We are using below code in ionic

We using file and file-transfer plugin.

Video will be downloaded in the on my iPhone and app folder

```
const transfer = this.transfer.create();
var directory = this.file.documentsDirectory;
directory = directory + "video.mp4";
fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(data.url), directory).then((entry) => {
   console.log(entry);
}).catch((error: FileTransferError) => {
   console.log(error);     
});
```

it does not showing in photo library.

What need do to show the video in photo library ionic ios